# Como posso fazer um if se os dados da DataBase for True ou False

Tags: c#, sql-server

Como posso fazer um if verificando se os dados de uma coluna na tabela da DataBase é True ou False?

Por exemplo:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT LoginID,Award FROM Sys_Usuarios_Award WHERE LoginID={login.LoginId} and Award='true ou false'", connection))
```

Oque tenho em mente:

```
if (Award == True){
Console.WriteLine("True");
}else{
Console.WriteLine("False");
}
```

Award é a coluna que eu peguei no SQLCommand.
Resumindo queria fazer um if com os dados bit de uma coluna mas não sei como fazer.

Comment: Se a coluna é `bit`, true=1 e false=0, então algo como `and (Award=1 or Award=0)` mas não entendi o propósito desse **OU**, já que o campo só pode assumir esses valores... ele é *nullable*? Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: É só de exemplo, pode ser tanto true como false, eu só quero fazer um if, se for True, Console.WriteLine("True"); , se for False Console.WriteLine("False"); Editei para explicar melhor

Comment: Pensei que estivesse falando de como fazer na `query`, mas no código depende de como vem seus dados, `DataReader`, `DataTable`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira simples é utilizando o SqlDataReader, exemplo abaixo:

```
using (var comando = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    comando.CommandText = $"SELECT LoginID,Award FROM Sys_Usuarios_Award WHERE LoginID={login.LoginId}";
    var reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read())
    {
        if ((bool)reader["Award"])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("True");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("False");
        }
    }
}
```